# Eject connected external hard drive using cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, ms-dos, diskpart, eject

Is there any way to eject external hard drive safely which is currently connected to the pc only using cmd?
I can only use cmd right now and GUI is out the question.

Comment: I know you can use `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll` to bring up wizard to eject USB device. See if you can Google about `Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll` and see if there's an api method or some parameter you can pass such as UUID, deviceID, or hardware name or something like that to always eject the needed device. If you can do it with C# or C code, you can run that in PowerShell which you can in turn run using native cmd only and windows CMD native with nothing further needed, period.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command below and consider changing the `ParseName` parameter with your drive letter

Single line using the **Run** dialog or **CMD**:

```
powershell (New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Namespace(17).ParseName(\"E:\").InvokeVerb(\"Eject\")
```

Using **PowerShell**

```
powershell (New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Namespace(17).ParseName("E:").InvokeVerb("Eject")
```

*it seems that, below option in some cases only remove the drive latter.*

Use the diskpart utility to safely remove a disk drive. This is useful when you have no GUI, for example in Server Core or Hyper-V Server.

1. On command prompt, type `diskpart` and wait for the new prompt, then type `list volume`. Take note of the number of your desired volume by watching its drive letter (be carefull!!!)
2. Type `select volume <number>`, where  is the number of your USB storage.
3. Then, type `remove all dismount`. Type `exit` to leave diskpart. Enjoy! ;)
4. Now you can safely remove your USB storage device from the Hyper-V server.

According to the diskpart remove's help (type "help remove" inside diskpart):

Comment: I have tried doing this but the hard drive’s led is still flashing.. usually it stops flashing after ejecting..

Comment: @ManavSinghChauhan , you are right, kindly check the updated answer, i hope this could help you